# Anyway to average different confusion matrices?

Tags: python, pandas, confusion-matrix

I have 3 separate classifiers, with 10 fold cross validation.
I output a confusion matrix (for each run/fold) each time as such:

```
cm = pd.crosstab(pd.Series(y_pred), pd.Series(y_test), rownames=['Predicted'], colnames=['Actual'], margins=True)
```

Is there any way I can create an average confusion matrix? I'd rather use pandas than sklearn cm unless I have to.

Answer (score 2):

You can [concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.concat.html) cross-tabulation frames, [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) their index values and take their [means](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# some random data frames
y_pred = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10)
y_test = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10)
cm1 = pd.crosstab(pd.Series(y_pred), pd.Series(y_test), rownames=['Predicted'], colnames=['Actual'], margins=True)
...

print(cm1)
Actual  0   1   All
Predicted           
0       2   4   6
1       1   3   4
All     3   7   10

print(cm2)    
Actual  0   1   All
Predicted           
0       6   2   8
1       1   1   2
All     7   3   10
```

[pandas.concat()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.concat.html) takes a sequence as its first argument (pandas objects to be concatenated), thus you can concatenate as many as you want by giving a list or tuples.

```
cm_concat = pd.concat((cm1, cm2))
cm_group = cm_concat.groupby(cm_concat.index)

cm_group.mean()
```

Resulting in:

```
    Actual  0   1   All
Predicted           
0           4   3   7
1           1   2   3
All         5   5   10
```